# getting Exception while calling function

Tags: powershell

if I call function I am getting exception

I am using the return value in for loop

```
2020-08-19T09:25:31.6470906Z row count:: 1
2020-08-19T09:25:31.6495736Z row count:: trns 1 System.Data.DataRow
2020-08-19T09:25:31.7884278Z ##[error]Cannot compare "System.Data.DataRow" because it is not IComparable.
2020-08-19T09:25:33.4007345Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
function getResultlist($sqlquery ){

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $sqlserver; Database = $sqldatabasename; User ID = $sqlusername; Password = $sqlpassword; Connection Timeout=0"
$sqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlquery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$rowCount = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count
Write-Host "row count::" $rowCount
return $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows
```

I am using this function  is as follow. I am getting this function result into variable and using in for loop

```
$rowCountTrn = getResultlist($testQuery)
Write-Host "row count:: trns" $rowCountTrn

if ($rowCountTrn -gt 0) {
    $mailtabData = $null
    
    foreach ($row in  $rowCountTrn ) {
        
            $mailtabData += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td><td>" + $row[2] + "</td></tr>"
            $sendemail = $true
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception message? Please paste the full error message.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to call/execute the function when you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to this statement:

```
if($rowCountTrn -gt 0){
```

When PowerShell sees the `-gt` comparison operator, it has to figure out a way to *compare* the two values. The left-hand side operand, `$rowCountTrn`, is an array of `DataRow` objects, and `DataRow` is *not* a comparable type (it doesn't implement the [`IComparable` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable)), so the expression fails with the error you're seeing.

If you want to ensure that at least one data row was returned, use `Count`:

```
if($rowCountTrn.Count -gt 0){
```